# Error while performing click on link

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, casperjs

i want to perform click on the link highlighted in image

[image: where i want to click]

but it is not performing click on it.
my code:

```
var w = div.getElementsByClassName('col5')[0];
w = w.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();
```

Comment: You want to trigger the event?

Comment: yes. if it helps
click on this link adds program for recording..

Comment: It is .click(), not .click, and you should use dispatchEvent anyway.

Comment: Is your code within `window.onload = function()`?

Comment: I don't think you need the `.innerHTML`.

Comment: - harry still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer:

```
casper.thenClick(xp('//*[@id="tap-on-8438-161-450-35-2013"]'), function() {
    console.log("Switched Off for Recording and Continuous Recording");
});
```